# How to keep users from breaking push button switches

Tags: switches, enclosure, mechanical, mechanical-assembly

I'm designing an enclosure for a device with a push button switch. The external button on the enclosure is physically large so I am concerned people will apply too much force and break the switch or break the switch off the board (if it's a right angle push button switch).

Most push button switches either have to be bottomed out or have a small widow where they are active so it doesn't seem like I can design the enclosure to ensure the user can always activate the switch but not allow the user to bottom out or over travel the switch.

I realize this is in someways a mechanical question but in other ways it's a question about the robustness of switches and I'm not finding much information on this.

How do I design for a push button momentary switch or what switch do I use to ensure that the user won't break it?

Comment: You can use some military-grade buttons.. But these are expensive.

Comment: put a spring between the button and the switch?

Comment: Look for "vandal resistant switches" - these have definite stops that prevent overtravel - but most are panel mount to avoid the forces being transferred to the board.

Comment: If the switch is right-angle to the board, and you are concerned about force, I would not mount it to the board at all. Panel mount a switch and use a connector to the board. This takes the stress relief off of the board and connectors itself.

Comment: You have a mechanical pushbutton, that bottoms out in its own housing, which activates a separate switch.

Comment: Look at the Eaton Cutler-Hammer 10250T line of buttons and switches. They are heavy-duty industrial switches. They are not cheap, but likely not as expensive as miltary-grade. Also consider the Rockwell Allen-Bradley 800T/H line.

Comment: use a button that uses a microswitch, such as this one ... https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9181 .... or build a limited travel hinged panel into the enclosure and use one of these underneath http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/251772927142-0-1/s-l1000.jpg

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas. I do need a very low cost switch (button) so the nice eaton or mil ones are out. I could do a design with a intermediary spring or a microswitch mechanism like that cool spark fun design (thanks for that) but I was really hoping there was a simpler way or just a low cost swith with more over travel rather than adding mechanical complexity for such a seemingly simple problem.

I have designed a mechanical housing that bottoms out before the switch bottoms out, but the problem is the switch buttons I'm finding have so much tolerance I can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: use a microswitch ... the contacts always close before the switch actuator reaches end of travel ... or use an optical slot sensor from an old mechanical mouse

Answer (score 3):

Arcade games have pretty robust switches, maybe start there. Crossing signal switches are another place to look.

A general approach would be to use a separate mechanical button with tough design that actuated the separate switch.

You could also use an optical proximity type behind gorilla glass if tactile feedback isn’t needed. Or use a light pipe behind a tough panel to do the same thing (I’ve seen crossing signals like this.)

Comment: We used to purchase arcade buttons and switches for the Museum displays that we used to make.  Check out "Happ Controls".  I think they may have been purchased by another company but they still have all of the arcade stuff available.

Comment: I have a design with the external button having a hard stop to prevent switch damage, but my problem is that many switches have little to no over travel. So far example it activates by 2mm minimum 3 mm maximum and no overtravel, so it's impossible to ensure you activate the switch and simultaneous ensure you don't apply excess force to the switch, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Maybe the just have enough flex and robustness to handle it if they have board alignment pins etc.

capactive/prox is too power intensive for this application.

Comment: hacktastical, could you clarify what a crossing signal switch is?  I tried looking it up to no avail.

Comment: A signal for a pedestrian crosswalk.

Answer (score 1):

Either mount the button to the chassis and use flexible wiring to the PCB, or mount the PCB so it is supported at one corner by the switch and can move sufficiently to absorb the maximum deformation that can be passed through the switch.